# akonadi server doesn't start after kubuntu upgrade to 13.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, akonadi

from .xsession-errors:

```
ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
search paths:  ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin", "/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin") 
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'initConnection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
Database error: Cannot open database.
Last driver error: "QMYSQL: Unable to connect"
Last database error: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/deric/.local/share/akonadi/socket-d630/mysql.socket' (2)"
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
Unable to open database "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/deric/.local/share/akonadi/socket-d630/mysql.socket' (2) QMYSQL: Unable to connect"
"[
0: akonadiserver() [0x418114]
1: akonadiserver() [0x418541]
2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x370b0) [0x7fd2b409c0b0]
3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fd2b409c037]
4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fd2b409f698]
5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc+0x122) [0x7fd2b5b4f5c2]
6: akonadiserver() [0x41a3eb]
7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN9QIODevice5writeEPKcx+0xb4) [0x7fd2b5be99f4]
8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x11662f) [0x7fd2b5bf462f]
9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QTextStreamD1Ev+0x3b) [0x7fd2b5bfcbcb]
10: akonadiserver() [0x41d2cd]
11: akonadiserver() [0x41e487]
12: akonadiserver() [0x411f43]
13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fd2b4086ea5]
14: akonadiserver() [0x4128d1]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed in `~/.config/akonadi/akonadiserverrc` path to socket, to match with the one generated by akonadi

```
Options="UNIX_SOCKET=/home/deric/.local/share/akonadi/socket-d630/akonadiserver.socket"
```

then start the service:

```
akonadictl start
```